# split json file based on number of objects

Tags: ubuntu, json, split

I have a file that contains objects. The object starts with a `{` and ends with `}`. There are other internal brackets `{ }` in some items like chain but they have indentation. The file I have is very large so I could not parse the `json` file. I want to split the objects into several files. I want a full object in each file (I can not split a single object in the middle between two files. If this happens, I can not parse the file.

How to achieve this? The normal `split` will not consider keeping full object inside file. I can identify the object by "host" and its start and end by `{ }` at the beginning of a line without indentation. Is there a way to split files based on the number of objects?

```
{
  "host": "a.com",
  "ip": "1.2.2.3",
  "port": 8,
  "chain": [
  {
    "version": 3,
    "subject": "xx"
  },  {
    "version": 3,
    "subject": "xx"
  } ]
}
{
  "host": "b.com",
  "ip": "2.5.0.4",
  "port": 3
  "chain": [
  {
    "version": 3,
    "subject": "xx"
  },  {
    "version": 3,
    "subject": "xx"
  } ]
}
{
  "host": "c.com",
  "ip": "9.17.6.7",
  "port": 4
}
```

Comment: How are you parsing the JSON file? The `jq` utility would probably be able to handle it without the need to split it.

Comment: jq found an error.

Comment: For anyone wanting to help you with this issue, and thus wanting to find a way to parse your data, that error would be important to know about.

Comment: Thanks. After hours of debugging, I figured the problem. I was adding `,` after each `}`. But I should not add one after the last `}`.

Answer (score 0):

I will assume that the JSON input document is syntactically correct (the document in the question lacks a comma on line 18).

Since the input consists of a set of independent objects, you may use `jq` with its `-c` (`--compact-output`) option,

```bash
jq -c . file
```

... to convert each object into "compact" form (one object per line).

Doing this makes it possible to apply `split` to the data without splitting any single object.

The example below uses the correct data from the question, and then splits this using `split` into one file per object:

```bash
$ jq -c . file
{"host":"a.com","ip":"1.2.2.3","port":8,"chain":[{"version":3,"subject":"xx"},{"version":3,"subject":"xx"}]}
{"host":"b.com","ip":"2.5.0.4","port":3,"chain":[{"version":3,"subject":"xx"},{"version":3,"subject":"xx"}]}
{"host":"c.com","ip":"9.17.6.7","port":4}
```

```bash
$ jq -c . file | split -l 1
```

```bash
$ ls
file    xaa     xab     xac
$ cat xaa
{"host":"a.com","ip":"1.2.2.3","port":8,"chain":[{"version":3,"subject":"xx"},{"version":3,"subject":"xx"}]}
$ cat xab
{"host":"b.com","ip":"2.5.0.4","port":3,"chain":[{"version":3,"subject":"xx"},{"version":3,"subject":"xx"}]}
$ cat xac
{"host":"c.com","ip":"9.17.6.7","port":4}
```